# How to have header on top of the slider

Tags: html, css

This is the current state:

[image: 'asd']

and I want it like this:

[image: 'asd']
I have done editing through photoshop to show my desired output. I have tried many things but i'm not successful.

This is the HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
  <h1>Maxtergo - Guaranteed Perfect Product</h1>
  <nav class='main-menu'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class='active' href='#'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Feature</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id='slider'>
  <div id='bannerscollection_zoominout_opportune'>
    <div class='myloader'></div>
    <!-- CONTENT -->
      <ul class="bannerscollection_zoominout_list">

          <li data-initialZoom="0.77" data-finalZoom="0.77" data-horizontalPosition="left" data-verticalPosition="center" data-text-id="#bannerscollection_zoominout_photoText2" ><img src="images/02_opportune.jpg" alt="" width="2500" height="1172" /></li>


          <li data-initialZoom="0.77" data-finalZoom="0.77" data-horizontalPosition="left" data-verticalPosition="center" data-text-id="#bannerscollection_zoominout_photoText3" ><img src="images/03_opportune.jpg" alt="" width="2500" height="1172" /></li>


          <li data-initialZoom="0.77" data-finalZoom="0.77" data-horizontalPosition="left" data-verticalPosition="center" data-text-id="#bannerscollection_zoominout_photoText4" ><img src="images/04_opportune.jpg" alt="" width="2500" height="1172" /></li>

          <li data-initialZoom="0.77" data-finalZoom="0.77" data-horizontalPosition="left" data-verticalPosition="center" data-text-id="#bannerscollection_zoominout_photoText5" ><img src="images/05_opportune.jpg" alt="" width="2500" height="1172" /></li>
```

And no css is on the slider.
and this is header CSS:

```
header {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: Try `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` on the header

Comment: Have done it already. The header just go below the slider and slider hides it.

Comment: ok then try adding `z-index: 999999` - if your slider has a `z-index` set then set the header `z-index` higher

Comment: Please post the answer. so that I can tick it.

Comment: But now the header is not centered.

Comment: Try the updated answer

Comment: I will tick your answer. Thanks alot. It isnt letting me tick right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure your header is shown above add z-index

```css
header {
    z-index: 99999;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    width: 960px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly wrap up your both of your `<header>` and "slider" inside a
>   wrapper. Make sure that you have to provide it position "relative". 
>   After that you have to go for making `<header>` as position absolute and
>   provide height and width as per your requirements. Then you must have to
>   add z-index to `<header>`. your `<header>` styles we will code here'll
>   look like this:

```css
header {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:auto;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```